# How do I write this code in non-conditional expression?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def filt(lst,n):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    return ([lst[0]] if lst[0] >= n else []) + filt(lst[1:],n)
```

So I want to write the last line like "normal", (i.e, not with "if" and "else" in one single line) Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate it into two, and have the `filt(lst[1:], n)` appended to both separately. Or you could take the `filt(lst[1:], n)` into a separate variable:

```
def filt(lst,n):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    next_value = filt(lst[1:], n)
    if lst[0] >= n:
        return lst[0] + next_value
    else:
        return [] + next_value
```